# Question about "On some sequences of integers" (Erdös, Turán)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, arithmetic-progressions

I was reading "On some sequences of integers" by Erdös and Turán, and was having some trouble following one of the arguments. You can find the paper [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/erdosturan.pdf)

Right after the proof of Theorem 2, they say:

> By a similar but very much longer argument we find that $$r(18)=r(19)=r(20)=8.$$ On the other hand, $r(21)=9$, since $1,3,4,8,9,16,18,19,21$ is an $A$ sequence; further, $$r(22)=r(23)=9.$$ Hence, as previously, we find that, for sufficiently large $N>N(\epsilon)$, $$r(N)<\left(\frac38+\epsilon\right)N.$$

But I don't really understand why this implies the $\frac38$ bound. I'm assuming you want to say something about $r(2\cdot 21+1)$ or something, using the fact that $r(m+n)\le r(m)+r(n)$, but I just don't see it.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that he does induction with 23 the same way he did with 17, getting:

$$ r(23) = 9 \Rightarrow r(2^4 + 2^3 - 1) = 9 \Rightarrow r(2^{k+4} + 2^{k+3} - 1) \leq 9 * 2^k $$

Then, we have:

$$ \frac{r(2^{k+4} + 2^{k+3} - 1)}{(2^{k+4} + 2^{k+3} - 1)} \leq \frac{9 * 2^k}{(2^{k+4} + 2^{k+3} - 1)} = \frac{3}{8 - 2^{-k}3^{-1}} \sim \frac{3}{8} + \epsilon $$